# How to pass textbox value to src link in HTML and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to enter video name to textbox, press ENTER button then browser play video I have stored in my disk. But I don't know how to get textbox value to HTML video src.

This link "love.mpe" is fixed. How can I replace it with value I enter textbox?

[image]

Here is my code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function nhap_so(value)
 {
  document.getElementById("txtText").value += value;
 }
 function clearText() 
 {
     document.getElementById("txtText").value = "";
 }
 function playVideo() 
 { 
     myVideo.play(); 
 } 

 function stopVideo() 
 { 
     myVideo.pause(); 
 } 
 /*function getValue()
 {
  var myString = document.getElementById("txtText").value;
  return myString;
  
 }*/
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="demo_getvalue.js"></script>
```

```html
<body>
<input name="txtText" type="text" id="txtText" size="20" maxlength="10" disabled="disabled"/>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" value="1" width="20" height="20" onclick="nhap_so(1);" id="so_1"  />
<input type="button" value="2" width="20" height="20" onclick="nhap_so(2);" id="so_2" />
<input type="button" value="3" width="20" height="20" onclick="nhap_so(3);" id="so_3" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="4" width="20" height="20" onclick="nhap_so(4);" id="so_4"  />
<input type="button" value="5" width="20" height="20" onclick="nhap_so(5);" id="so_5" />
<input type="button" value="6" width="20" height="20" onclick="nhap_so(6);" id="so_6" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="7" width="20" height="20" onclick="nhap_so(7);" id="so_7"  />
<input type="button" value="8" width="20" height="20" onclick="nhap_so(8);" id="so_8" />
<input type="button" value="9" width="20" height="20" onclick="nhap_so(9);" id="so_9" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="0" width="20" height="20" onclick="nhap_so(0);" id="so_0" />
<input type="button" value="ENTER" width="20" height="20" onclick="getValue();"/>
<input type="button" value="CLEAR" width="20" height="20" onclick="clearText();"/>
<br />
<br />
<video id="myVideo" width="640" height="360">
  <source src="love.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
<br />
<br />
<input type="button"  value="PLAY" width="20" height="20" onclick="playVideo();" />
<input type="button" value="PAUSE" width="20" height="20" onclick="stopVideo();" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `getValue()` function to `changeValue()` and change its code to this:

```
changeValue () {
 newVal = document.getElementById('txtText').value;
 document.getElementById('myVideo').firstChild.src = newVal + ".mp4";
}
```

Make sure to *uncomment* it so it works.

Comment: Its simple. Look I have edited the code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I think document.getElementById("myVideo").innerHTML = '<source src="'+newVal+'.mp4" type="video/mp4" >'; it will work

Answer (score 0):

1.Make you HTML like this

```
<video id='videoPlayer' width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
   <source id='mp4Source' src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source id='oggSource' src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

2.Get get Textbox value

```
var VideoLink = document.getElementById("myText").value;
```

3: now set the source

```
var player = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');

      var mp4Vid = document.getElementById('mp4Source');

      player.pause();

      // Now simply set the 'src' attribute of the mp4Vid variable!!!!
      // (...using the jQuery library in this case)

      $(mp4Vid).attr('src', VideoLink);

      player.load();
      player.play();
```